# How to change aws credentials in Serverless 1.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I try to use Serverless 1.0, with several AWS credentials.
(In my PC, 1.3.0 is installed)

I found some descriptions that "admin.env" can change credentials in Stack overflow or github issues, but I can't found how to write and where to put admin.env.
Are there any good document for admin.env?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First create different profiles. Use cli(this works from 1.3.0, won't work in 1.0.0, not sure which you are using since you mention both):

```
serverless config credentials --provider aws --key 1234 --secret 5678 --profile your-profile-name
```

Then in your `serverless.yml` file you can set the profile you want use:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  stage: dev
  profile: your-profile-name
```

If you want to automatically deploy to different profiles depending on the stage you define variables and reference them in your `serverless.yml` file.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.defaultStage}
  profile: ${self:custom.profiles.${self:provider.stage}}
custom:
  defaultStage: dev
  profiles:
    dev: your-profile-name
    prod: another-profile-name
```

Or you can reference your profile name in any other way. Read about variables in serverless-framework. You can get the name of profile to use from another file, from cli or from the same file(like in the example I gave).

More about the variables: 
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/

Comment: "Variable" concept is so smart!